# C program to find the rotation matrix (orientation) of a 6DOF robot from its end effector position and link parameters

Tags: inverse-kinematics, orientation, c

I'm writing a C program to find the inverse kinematics of a 6DOF robot. I've been able to write it successfully based on the general concept of Inverse Kinematics using DH parameters (i.e. finding the joint angles of the robot from its known orientation and position).

But I only have the values of the position of the robot's end effector, and link parameters (link lengths, link twists and the distance between links). How do I calculate the orientation of the robot's end effector with these values?

I'll be glad if someone can help. I'm also open to further questions for clarifications. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe someone else can give a more detailed answer, but my first reaction was that you can't. You have a 6 DOF robot but you're only fixing 3 degrees of freedom (x/y/z position). The other three (roll/pitch/yaw) could be anything.

Comment: Agree with Chuck.

Comment: Have you obtain forward kinematic matrix? You can get orientation from there

Comment: @Chuck That's my point. I'm looking for a way to find the RPY of the robot.

Comment: @AlbertHM thanks for your response. Yes, I've been able to obtain forward kinematic matrix. And yes I was able to come up with equations to find the orientation matrix. 
But to find the numeric values of the orientation matrix using Forward Kinematics, I have to know the numeric values of the joint angles (Theta) of the robot....but I don't know them. 

That's why I asked if there's a way to find the joint angles knowing only the final position of the robot's EE and its link parameters

Comment: @Chuck How do I find the RPY of a robot? I intend to get numeric results, not just placeholder variables.
Thanks so much for your response earlier

Comment: Ok I got your point; known variable : position of end effector and link length; unknown variable : orientation matrix and joint angle value. Then is it possible to know joint angle? The answer is no. Because several joint configuration can have the exact same position but different orientation. To solve what you face now, either you find the joint angle or the orientation of end-effector. If you can find orientation and position,then you can simply perform inverse kinematic.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response @AlbertHM 

How do I find the orientation of the end-effector?

Comment: @izu201ph - I think Albert and I are saying the same thing here - you can either know all of your joint angles and can do forward kinematics to determine your end effector position and orientation, or you can know the position and orientation and use inverse kinematics to find the joint angles. To help visualize what we're saying, look at [Beyonce doing the hand dance](https://tenor.com/view/beyonce-singleladies-hand-nothing-i-dontknow-gif-5252008) - her palm can be facing towards you or away from you. Her arm bones are fixed and you know where her hand is, but the rotation is not fixed.

Comment: Pose is position **and** orientation. Position alone is not enough to fix the pose unless the orientation depends on the pose, but if that's the case then you have a 3DOF robot, not a 6DOF robot.

Comment: Well, you can try to stick imu on end effector, get rpy angle, convert it into axis angle orientation representation, then perform inverse kinematic. But seriously, just try to find the joint angle.

Comment: @Chuck Okay thank you very much. I get you.

Comment: @AlbertHM Okay, thank you very much. I'll look into that

Comment: Generalized coordinates () has six components - three for position and three for rotation. Forward Kinematics should let you transform not only position from initial frame to end effector but also its orientation.
https://users.cs.duke.edu/~brd/Teaching/Bio/asmb/current/Papers/chap3-forward-kinematics.pdf